# Is there a CDN for large files that doesn't need a manual upload?

Tags: cdn

I have a MaxCDN account. I am using their pull zones and it works perfectly (they autoamtically download .css, .js etc from my server)

Now I would like to use the cdn for large file too, but MaxCDN's Push Zones requires me to manually upload the files.

Is there a CDN that automatically grabs large files?

Comment: Are you *specifically* looking for another CDN, or is the real problem the assumption that uploads have to happen manually? My understanding is that MaxCDN supports rsync. Just set up a cron job and walk away. I don't actually use MaxCDN, though, so can't point you at any detailed documentation. But it's mentioned several times throughout the [pre-sale FAQ](http://support.maxcdn.com/general/pre-sale-questions/) and a few other spots.

Comment: looking for antoher cdn, because MaxCDN (except rsync) doens't support that

Comment: You should edit your question to make this clearer. The problem is not manual uploading as in your question, or even automated uploading, ie. via rsync. You want the CDN to come to you. (Which I'm not sure of the likelihood of, to be honest.)

Comment: come to me?.... I just want CDN to download my files from my server autoamtically like it was .css or this kind of file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My only experience is with big CDN providers like Akamai and Limelight. For them, you simply setup a new CNAME to them and have the CDN point to an origin domain to automatically pull all the files when there's a cache miss.

For example, on your site you display this:

mycdnfiles.mysite.com/mybigimage.png

That domain is a CNAME to the CDN. On the CDN you specify the origin for your files which means the CDN will go here, for example, to get the content:

origin.mysite.com/mybigimage.png

Comment: this works with MaxCDN too but with only small files like .png and ohters. With big files (.zip, .exe ecc) you will have to mnaually uploade them

Answer (score 0):

1. Amazon AWS service has an API: http://aws.amazon.com/
2. I don't think that there's a service that can "grab" files, but there are clients that work like FTP which you can use to upload, or, you can write a code that will automate the upload.